# Can Gauss' Law apply to an irregular 3D region?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, charge, gauss-law

Let's say I have this configuration:

[image]

The figure above is a cube with a charge **not** in the center.

Can I calculate the flux through the surfaces using Gauss' Law, or does it only apply when the charge is in the center?

Comment: You can apply Gauss's law, even if the charge is not at the center.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Gauss's law is valid for this scenario.

However, since there's no particular symmetry in the problem, you can't assume the flux through all sides of the cube is equal. Therefore you can't write a simple expression for the flux through a particular side by inspection like you could if the charge were centered in the cube.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can calculate it through Gauss Law as, according to the law Total flux depends upon total charge enclosed by the gaussian surface(here the cube)
Total flux=q/Eo[Eo is permittivity of free space having value 8.854×10^(-12) C²/N-m²]
It doesn't depend upon where the charge is placed inside the gaussian surface it only depends upon how much charge is present inside the surface.
To find the flux through each surface of the cube divide Total flux through cube by 6(if the charge is present at the symmetrical centre of the cube)

Comment: Your last step ("divide the total flux by 6") only works if the charge distribution within the cube is all at the center of the cube, or otherwise has the same symmetry as the cube. If the charge is all at a point other than the center of the cube, this step gives an incorrect result.

Comment: Yaa, sorry my fault ....thanks for rectifying me!!